# Error generating the bundle. See output window for details

Tags: web-essentials, bundles

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Update 3 and I have installed the latest version of Web Essentials (updated 8/8/2014), but I receive this error about 90% of the time I build or save. I even check out the source js/html files and all the existing files in the bundles folder from TFS before building. Any ideas on what else I can do?

Error generating the bundle. See output window for details

```
System.ArgumentException: The parameter is incorrect. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070057 (E_INVALIDARG))
   at EnvDTE.Properties.Item(Object index)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.ProjectHelpers.AddFileToActiveProject(String fileName, String itemType)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleFilesMenu.<GenerateAsync>d__2d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at MadsKristensen.EditorExtensions.BundleFilesMenu.<UpdateBundleAsync>d__22.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated Visual Studio 2013 to Update 4 and updated to the Web Essentials for Update 4 and that appeared to fix the issue.